# Migrating from Wordpress MU to single site

Tags: wordpress

I have seen alot of information on migrating from wordpress Single User to Multi user but don't see any on migrating from MU to SU.  I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.   I don't want to have to rebuild the sites manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean automatically translate the WPMU sites into individual WP installations? I doubt anything exists. It would involve copying WP files, making necessary directories and creating configuration files, all the DB tables, dealing with the differences in DB and files from WP vs WPMU (image storage, plugins, etc)...

One solution, provided you have a handful of sites and not hundreds, can be to export the blog content via wp-admin > tools > export and importing back via wp-admin > tools > import once you have the new blog running. You will probably have to adjust the path for the images on the exporting XML files to agree with WP directory structure.

Comment: Thanks What I considered was trying to do something just like that I made a start on it.  I  have about 10 sites to migrate and perhaps it would make more sense to move them manually.   If I were do try to automate the process with a shell script what steps would be needed.  I have actually begun to try to write that script but am sure that i don't have all that I need.

Comment: Hi If I use the wordpress import export how do I adjust

Comment: Yes, I agree, for 10 sites it won't be worth it, although of course you could make the world a favor if you do the shell script and share it! Let me know please ;). Apart from the things I pointed out, I am afraid I can't be of much more help, I haven't got much experience with MU.

Comment: Sorry, I post the last comment before I saw your new one. I made that import/export move once, and I didn't have any problem apart from the images paths, for which I just opened the XML in a text editor and did a search for the path replacing the MU for the WP one, something like '/wp-content/blogs.dir/blogIDnumber/files' for MU and '/wp-cotent/uploads' for WP.

Comment: I am going to do a manual export.  I am happy to post the shell script that I have and maybe someone else slamming it will be good for me and it might be a useful basis for someone else.  How do I do that though?

Comment: Sharing your script you mean? I would use Github, it is free for public repositories, or their Gist section: https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you just use the Export function. It's the easiest way, really.

No scripts exists that I know of, no posts either, because it's just like moving a blog off wordpress.com.

Except you can access the database if you need it.